# Laravel named route for resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.2, is it possible to assign a name to a resource controller route?  My route is defined as follows:

```
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController');
```

I tried adding a name option to the route like this:

```
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController', array("as"=>"faq"));
```

However, when I hit the /faq route and place `{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}` in my view, it  yields `faq.faq.index` instead of just `faq`.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

When you use a resource controller route, it automatically generates names for each individual route that it creates. `Route::resource()` is basically a helper method that then generates individual routes for you, rather than you needing to define each route manually.

You can view the route names generated by running `php artisan route:list` in your terminal/console. You can also see the types of route names generated on the [resource controller docs page](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controllers).

Here are the ways you can modify the names for resource controller routes:

**Change a single action's name entirely:**

```php
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController')
    ->name('index', 'list');

// GET faq -> list
```

Note that the original `faq.` prefix is NOT included when using `name()` on a single resource method. You have to replace this yourself.

**Change multiple actions' names entirely:**

You can call `name()` multiple times fluently:

```php
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController')
    ->name('index', 'faq.list')
    ->name('destroy', 'faq.delete');

// GET    faq       -> faq.list
// DELETE faq/{faq} -> faq.delete
```

OR, you can call `names()` and pass an array of methods and their names:

```php
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController')
    ->names([
        'index' => 'faq.list',
        'destroy' => 'faq.delete',
    ]);

// GET    faq       -> faq.list
// DELETE faq/{faq} -> faq.delete
```

Note that this also replaces the entire name and does not include the original `faq.` prefix. I included it here as an example of keeping the `faq.` prefix but changing the method name.

**Change only the resource segment of all method names:**

Call the `names()` method, passing a string of the desired resource segment instead of an array:

```php
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController')
    ->names('productfaq');

// GET  faq -> productfaq.index
// POST faq -> productfaq.store
// etc...
```

The new segment can include periods if it makes sense for your organization:

```php
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController')
    ->names('product.faq');

// GET  faq -> product.faq.index
// POST faq -> product.faq.store
// etc...
```

**Add the same prefix to every route name:**

See [Route Name Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-name-prefixes):

```php
Route::name('prefix')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController');
});

// GET  faq -> prefix.faq.index
// POST faq -> prefix.faq.store
// etc...
```

**Add a URI prefix *and* route name prefix to the whole resource:**

See [Route Group Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-prefixes), and include an `as()` call to modify the route names:

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->as('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController');
});

// GET  admin/faq -> admin.faq.list
// POST admin/faq -> admin.faq.create
// etc...
```

Comment: Hi I like this solution, but I wanna do it with controller route. Is there any way to do something like this: Route::controller('/', 'HomeController', ['names' => ['home.index' => 'getIndex']]);

Comment: @AndersonNunesdaSilva The solution is very similar to that, and is [described in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers).

Comment: @Aken Roberts Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594340/how-can-i-implement-resource-controllers-if-i-use-many-get-on-the-laravel

Comment: I didn't know about `as` key, thank you. Cleanest solution

Comment: The answer No. 2 is the best! I used it just after reading and it helped even in Laravel 8. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 43):

For answer seekers with Laravel 5.5+ finding this page:

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {

    Route::resource('users','UserController');

});
```

These options will result in the following for the *Resource*:

- `namespace()` sets Controller namespace to \Admin\UserController
- `prefix()` sets request URi to /admin/users
- `name()` sets route name accessor to `route('admin.users.index')`

> In `name()` the DOT is intended, it is not a typo.

Please let others know if this works in comments for any versions prior to Laravel 5.5, I will update my answer.

**Update:**

Taylor accepted my PR to officially document this in 5.5:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-name-prefixes

---

**UPDATE LARAVEL 8**

> New in Laravel 8, the need to use a `namespace` in route configs is deprecated, the default `namespace` wrapper in `RouteServiceProvider` has been removed from Laravel's standard config.
> This change decouples Controller namespaces from having to be considered when grouping routes, dropping the `namespace` requirement when registering routes gives much more freedom when organizing controllers and routes.

With Laravel 8, the original example in the top half of this post would now look as follows using self references to static class name:

```php
use \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\{
    UserController,
    ProductController,
    AnotherController,
}

Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {

    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);

    Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);

    Route::resource('another', AnotherController::class);

});
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594340/how-can-i-implement-resource-controllers-if-i-use-many-get-on-the-laravel

Answer (score 32):

I don't know if it's available in laravel 4.2 (I tested in 5.7) but you can use `names` to change the name of all routes generated by resource

```
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController', ['names' => 'something']);
```

and the result will be like this

```
something.index
```

and you don't need to specify each route

Comment: This is a really underrated answer.

Comment: where do you find this answer? is it in the documentation?

Answer (score 9):

All Updates Later then Laravel 5.5 Using

```
Route::resource('faqs', 'FaqController', ['as' => 'faqs']);
```

if we not use `['as' => 'faqs']` in above code then it will also work same.

[Updated]

Important to keep in mind that this will work for  "**resource**"

For example:

```
Route::resource('admin/posts/tags', 'PostTagController', ['as' => 'posts']);
```

and result will be like

```
 POST      | admin/posts/tags                  | posts.tags.store
 GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/tags                  | posts.tags.index
 GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/tags/create           | posts.tags.create
 DELETE    | admin/posts/tags/{tag}            | posts.tags.destroy
 PUT|PATCH | admin/posts/tags/{tag}            | posts.tags.update
 GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/tags/{tag}            | posts.tags.show
 GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/tags/{tag}/edit       | posts.tags.edit
```

Answer (score 5):

**Tested with Laravel 8:**

You can define your name for resource route as passing names as optional arguments. For Example:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\UsersController;

Route::resource('reservations', UsersController::class, ['names' => 'users']);
```

The above example defines routes such as `users.index`, `users.store` etc.

You can also pass the route names as:

```php
Route::resource('reservations', UsersController::class, ['names' => 'admin.users']);
```

which will define routes with prefix of `admin` such as `admin.users.index`, `admin.users.store`

Comment: on my end this does not generate the correct routes. for example the show route is generated as | GET|HEAD  | admin/clients/{}  --> empty curly brackets brings issues

Answer (score 4):

Using Laravel 5.5

```
Route::resource('admin/posts/tags', 'PostTagController', ['as' => 'posts']);
```

important to keep in mind the "**resource**"

For example, I send something from my project:

```
Route::resource('admin/posts/tags', 'PostTagController', ['as' => 'posts']);
```

Answer (score 4):

**And In Laravel 8**

```
Route::resource('product', 
    App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\ProductController::class, [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'admin.product.index', 
        'store' => 'admin.product.store', 
        'update' => 'admin.product.update', 
        'destroy' => 'admin.product.delete'
    ]
])->except(['edit', 'create']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::resource('nice-books', BookController::class)->names('books');
```

In this line, `->names('books')` serves as a `books.` name prefix to BookController resource routes.

Example effect: `route('books.index')` -> `GET /nice-books`

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: @SuperKai-KazuyaIto added. is everything clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Route::resource('articles','ArticleController', ['names' => 'xyz'])

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to set name in resource in laravel 5.7 that i have test it.
it auto generate route name from url.

Answer (score -1):

Got the same error as you.
for me it worked by adding the whole path that is namespace/ControllerName

Route::resource('staffs', 'App\Http\Controllers\StaffController');

Answer (score -2):

You can rename your `resource routes` in `AppServiceProvider.php` like so:

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::resourceVerbs([
        'create' => 'neu',
        'edit' => 'bearbeiten',
    ]);
}
```

I believe this feature is designed for `localization`.

Comment: Did you actually read the question?