# Route::resource change path names in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

When using RESTful resource controllers, we can use route::resource() to work with, but the URIs seem to be default.

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                | Name          | Action                                      | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                  |               | Closure                                     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | items              | items.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | items              | items.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | items/create       | items.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | items/{items}      | items.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | items/{items}      | items.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | items/{items}      | items.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | items/{items}/edit | items.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@edit    | web        |
|        | POST      | register           | signup        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@SignUp  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | signup             |               | Closure                                     | web        |
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
```

(ignore the first and the last two, we're looking at the 'items.something' routes)

I want to, for example, change "items/create" to "items/new".
On a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290229/laravel-named-route-for-resource-controller), the answer was "No", but since the question is over one year old and Laravel developments seems to be pretty fast, is there already a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer hasn't really changed. You can't customize a resource controller action directly. There is a workaround however: you can exclude it and add it yourself.

First make your resource route partial and exclude the action(s) you don't want:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

```
Route::resource('items', 'ItemController', ['except' => [
    'create'
]]);
```

Then you can add your own routes in addition:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

```
Route::get('items/new', 'ItemController@new');
```

Make sure to stick that before the `resource` route, as mentioned in the docs.

Note you *can* customize the route name, as mentioned in that previous thread you linked to.

Comment: Too bad there isn't a real way, but I didn't think of partials. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well this answers the question but yuk! Either use the `::resource` shortcut or declare all the routes, its a lot easiers to understand whats going on that way

Comment: @Steve I agree completely. I've stopped using `resource` myself and specify all my routes explicitly. I like to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: I hear you both. I'm on v5.5 and encountering the same issue. will go on the same route: not using `resource` and defining my routes explicitly