# Route [settings] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\UserManagementSystem\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

> Route [settings] not defined. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\UserManagementSystem\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

I wanted to create a user profile updation. i created the blade fields and all necessary fields but when i run the program it shows the error

This is my web.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group( ['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');

Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
Route::resource('settings', 'SettingsController');
});
```

And my app.blade.php is

```
<a href="{{ route('settings') }}"
onclick="event.preventDefault();                                                 
document.getElementById('settings-form').submit();">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Settings
</a>

<form id="settings-form" action="{{ route('settings') }}" method="POST" 
style="display: none;">
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Any one please help me. I am stuck with my work

Comment: You're trying to access a route with name 'settings' but have no name for it. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290229/laravel-named-route-for-resource-controller

Answer (score 2):

Change your route() method to url() like shown bellow.

```html
<a href="{{ url('settings') }}"
onclick="event.preventDefault();                                                 
document.getElementById('settings-form').submit();">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Settings
</a>

<form id="settings-form" action="{{ url('settings') }}" method="POST" 
style="display: none;">
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

use`@store`for storing data in database

in .blade.php file

```
<form id="settings-form" action="{{ route('settings') }}" method="post">
```

`@csrf` `</form>`

In web.php

```
Route::post('settings', 'SettingsController@store')->name('settings');
```

Comment: Don´t forget to clear the route cache: php artisan route:cache

Answer (score 0):

Try `route('setting.{resource function-name}');`
like `route('setting.index)`
or `route('setting.show', ['id'=> 'setting_id']);`

instead of just `route('setting');`

you are using a

```
Route::resource('settings', 'SettingsController');
```

you have to specify which function using in a resource route.
If you want to know which function there are in your resource controller
check out this link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Route::get('settings', 'SettingsController')->name('settings');
```

or

```
Route::resource('settings', 'SettingsController')->name('settings);
```