# Laravel routing broken

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Hello I am trying to send an AJAX request to my `store` but instead it goes to `show`

```
        function submitForm() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'laptop/andy',
                data: {
                    routing: 'createM',
                    type: $('#type').val(),
                    body: $('#body').val()
                }
            })
        }
```

And if I try to do php artisan optimize I get this error:

```
   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919| 
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921|
```

The weird thing is, even though I've commented the `show` out of the controller, the engine still recognizes the route as valid.

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], static function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::get('requestSent', 'TicketController@requestSent')->name('requestSent');
    Route::get('requestBusy', 'TicketController@requestBusy')->name('requestBusy');
    Route::get('requestAccepted', 'TicketController@requestAccepted')->name('requestAccepted');
    Route::get('requestDone', 'TicketController@requestDone')->name('requestDone');
    Route::resource('ticket', 'TicketController');

    Route::get('/phpmyadmin', static function () {
       return view('phpmyadmin');
    })->name('phpMyAdmin');

    Route::resource('laptop', 'LaptopController');

    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

    Route::get('/servicepakket', static function () {
        return view('servicepakket');
    })->name('service');

    Route::get('requestRecent', static function () {
        return view('test');
    });
});
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the route isn't stored in the controller.. It's stored in routes/web.php. Commenting out the route in the controller won't do much

Comment: Could you add your routes to the question.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript its a resource controller.

Comment: Let us to see your routes/web.php.

Comment: It also seems like you're asking about two different issues. It goes to the wrong route and that you can't optimize (even though I think the error message is pretty clear on that one). Stick to one question per post.

Comment: No need to be rude. I'm just pointing out that questions here should contain one issue per post or they will be considered to be too broad and unfocused and are more likely of getting closed.

Comment: The uri for the post method for that route is `/laptop` not `/laptop/andy`

Comment: and do u have a `store` method in your `LaptopController`?

Comment: what if you try to set your AJAX url as `'{{ route("laptop.store") }}'`?

Comment: For the `artisan optimize` error, make sure none of your routes (both in `routes/web.php` and `routes/api.php` have closures in them (read the Basic Routing section of the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#basic-routing) if you don't know what route closures are). Routes with closures prevent commands like `artisan optimize` and `artisan route:cache` from working.

Comment: and why do u want to use a route called laptop/andy? What is "andy" in this context?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Right, that was the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @victorf 1. Yes, 2. the {{}} does not work in JS, and what if the code was in a JS file? 3. andy was the placeholder for store in case the store route was whats wrong with it. 4. I fixed it

Comment: @Alex Do you see a closure anywhere in my code?

Comment: @DanielMer Yes, multiple actually. `/phpmyadmin`, `/servicepakket` and `/requestRecent` all have closures, and that's just in `routes/web.php`. Given the error, there's a route in `routes/api.php` using closures as well.

Comment: @Alex I'm guessing you mean the / ?

Comment: No, the closure is the `static function () {}` bit and whatever's inside it. If you remove those bits and move them to controllers, calling them the same way you've done with your other routes (for example `Route::get('/phpmyadmin', 'HomeController@phpmyadmin')->name('phpmyadmin')`, you'll be able to run the `optimize` command.

Comment: @DanielMer Glad to contribute. I can not write an answer now, I was just reading and commented on the mobile, but it is difficult to write an answer from the mobile. Anyway it would be good to close the question with an accepted answer. Maybe you or someone else can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please send the name **andy** in POST data.

```
    function submitForm() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/laptop',
            data: {
                //routing: 'createM',
                name: 'andy',
                type: $('#type').val(),
                body: $('#body').val()
            }
        })
    }
```

Edit: I think there is no need for `routing` parameter in data. Because the `POST` operation will trigger the Store operation.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456577/1027360