# How can i submit form using name route when i am logged in with admin guard?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-routing, laravel-authentication, laravel-guard

im using multiple authentication using guards and i stuck with routing of resource Controller

**I have two Different Controllers with same name in different namespaces**

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('test','HomeController');
});

Route::namespace('Vendor')->prefix('vendor')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('test','HomeController');
});
```

**Now i have form for admin**

```
<form action="{{ route('test.store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When i submit this form it redirect to the controller of vendor store.

**Q. How can i submit form to the HomeController of admin namespace using **name route** when i am logged in with admin guard?**

Comment: You should add `->name('admin.')` and then `route('admin.test.store')`. I guess this will solve the issue.

Comment: yes i want do like this bur on complete resource route this apply only for single route. @maartenpaauw

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution we can differentiate both controller by using **'as'** with resource route like

```
Route::resource('test', 'HomeController',['as' => 'admin']);
```

after that i can use route name like `route(admin.test.index)`  and so on

got the refrence from 
[Laravel named route for resource controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290229/laravel-named-route-for-resource-controller)