# Laravel create link for prefix action

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a prefix called admin. My all controller in admin folder.

In route I have created route like below with namespace

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::resource('/tags', 'TagsController');

});
```

Now I am trying to create link in my admin panel sidebar

```
<a href="{{ url('admin/tags') }}" title="bookmark">Tags</a>
```

In table I have used action like below example

```
<a href="{{action('Admin\TagsController@show',['tag'=>$tag->id])}}" >View</a>
```

My question is how can I create both link without writing **admin** ? I have more then 100 unique link , I want to avoid to write this admin **prefix** every time in link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `route()` helper function to generate url's.

```
/**
 * Generate the URL to a named route.
 *
 * @param  array|string  $name
 * @param  mixed  $parameters
 * @param  bool  $absolute
 * @return string
 */
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
}
```

You may name route your prefix/resource routes like showed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48355590/2188922) and then use it in route function.

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
     Route::resource('/tags', 'TagsController');
});
```

Please execute `php artisan route:list` command to see if you named the routes correctly.

Comment: In name why do need this dot ?

Comment: @NiloyRony it is just a convention - (the post i shared is old) - maybe in the newer versions of the laravel it doesn't require it but automatically appends it.

Comment: I have tried in version 7.x , without dot it's not working.

Comment: @NiloyRony if you put without dot then name shouldn’t include dot after it - you may need to clear routes and run route list to see what it prints and use the one listed in your view files