# How to specify custom name for a Resource Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a Laravel 9 project and I have added this resource route:

```
Route::resource('users', UsersController::class);
```

So it basically takes the uri which is `users` and make the other route names like this:

`users.index`, `users.create`, `users.store`, etc

Now I need to put the resource in a route group with prefix of `users`, so the resource will be looked like this:

```
Route::prefix('users')->group(function () {
   Route::resource('/', UsersController::class);
});
```

Now because the uri for the resource route is empty, it can not add route names.

So I wonder how can I apply a custom name for the resource route in this situation.

I tried adding `Route::resource('/', UsersController::class)->name('users');` but this is wrong!

What is the proper way of applying custom route name for a resource route?

Comment: use third param to resources Route::resource('/', UsersController::class, ['names' => 'users']);

Comment: ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290229/laravel-named-route-for-resource-controller